# Convert 1 column data into multi hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary, dummy-variable

As an example to the problem, suppose we have a dataframe:

```
    Name Class
0   Aci  FB 
1   Dan  TWT
2   Ann  GRS
3   Aci  GRS
4   Dan  FB
```

The resulted dataframe would be
  df

```
   Name  FB   TWT  GRS
0  Aci   1    0   1
0  Dan   1    1   0
0  Ann   0    0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and aggregate `max` or `sum`:

```
#always 0,1 in output
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name')['Class']).max(level=0).reset_index()
#if need count values
#df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name')['Class']).sum(level=0).reset_index()

print (df1)
  Name  FB  GRS  TWT
0  Aci   1    1    0
1  Dan   1    0    1
2  Ann   0    1    0
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if I have more static columns to keep such as (Name)?

Comment: If need aggregtae by all this columns use `.set_index(['Name', 'another col'])`

Comment: @Codevan - if no aggregation `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.pop('Class')))`

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions were failing for me due to memory overflows when I have 315 samples and 1908 labels. Here are some more performant methods.

Using pandas pivot:

```
def multihotencode(data, samples_col, labels_col):
    data = data.copy()
    data['present'] = 1
    multihot = data.pivot(index=samples_col, columns=labels_col, values='present')
    return multihot.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Using sklearn:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

def multihotencode(data, samples_col, labels_col):

    ## Aggregate the labels into a tuple for each sample
    tupled = data.groupby(samples_col).apply(lambda x: tuple(x[labels_col].to_numpy()))

    ## Get multi-hot encoded matrix.
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    multihot = mlb.fit_transform(samplepgs)

    ## Reapply the index and column headers
    return pd.DataFrame(multihot, index=tupled.index, columns=mlb.classes_)
```

Both methods give the same result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Aci', 'FB'],
    ['Dan', 'TWT'],
    ['Ann', 'GRS'],
    ['Aci', 'GRS'],
    ['Dan', 'FB']
], columns=['Name', 'Class'])

multihotencode(df, 'Name', 'Class')
>>> 
    FB  GRS TWT
Name            
Aci 1   1   0
Ann 0   1   0
Dan 1   0   1
```